# Return multiple types from google places autocompleteService.getPlacePredictions

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to implement a custom UI for the google places autocomplete as the prebuilt one doesn't allow me to manually select results. Everything works when not using multiple types in the getPlacePredictions function options but when I use ['(regions)', '(cities)'] the status returns 'invalid request'

Am I doing something wrong or is it not possible to return multiple types?

```
var _this = this;

this.input = $('#zipcode_autocomplete');

this.service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();

this.input.on('input', function() {
  return _this.service.getPlacePredictions({
    input: _this.input.val(),
    types: ['(regions)', '(cities)'],
    componentRestrictions: {
      country: 'us'
    }
  }, _this.callback);
});

this.callback = function(predictions, status) {
  var i, prediction, _results;
  console.log(predictions);
  if (status !== google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    alert(status);
    return;
  }
  i = 0;
  prediction = void 0;
  this.results = $('ul.location_results').removeClass('hidden').html('');
  _results = [];
  while (prediction = predictions[i]) {
    this.results.append("<li><span class='location-address'>" + prediction.terms[0].value + "</span><span class='location-state'>" + prediction.terms[prediction.terms.length - 2].value + "</span></li>");
    _results.push(i++);
  }
  return _results;
};
```

Comment: According to the API ['In general only a single type is allowed'](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete#place_types).

Comment: Ok, that's frustrating, thanks for pointing me to the page, I couldn't find it anywhere.

@Andy if you want to post that as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: done. Added a little more info in there too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the API ['In general only a single type is allowed'](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete#place_types).

If you were to try to get both types individually what you could do is use a [deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) to manage the process, something like this:

```
// set a new promises array, set the types array
var promises = [], types = ['(regions)', '(cities)'];

// loop over the types and push the output of getPredications() for each one
// into the promises array
for (var i = 0, l = types.length; i < l; i++) {
  promises.push(getPredictions(types[i]));
}

// when all promises have completed then do something
// This uses jQuery's when method which can take an array of
// promises when used with apply
$.when.apply(null, promises).then(runThisFunction);

function getPredictions(type) {

  // Set up a new deferred object
  var deferred = new $.Deferred();

  // Call the asynchronous function to get the place predictions
  this.service.getPlacePredictions({
    input: _this.input.val(),
    types: type,
    componentRestrictions: {
      country: 'us'
    }
  }, function (data) {

    // Once the data has been returned perhaps do something with data
    // but definitely resolve the deferred object.       
    deferred.resolve();
  });

  // return the promise
  return deferred.promise();
}
```

Comment: I was trying to do something similar (pull data from my own source and Google) and you solution is only one on Google for such case. Unfortunately I have hard time understanding how this works exactly. Would you care to explain a little?

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel, I've added some notes. Take a look at the documentation for jQuery's [`deferred objects API`](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) for more information.

Comment: @MikeSzyndel I am trying to get the results based on "postal_code" and "address". I am having difficulty in understanding your code. Would you please help me in integrating your logic into my code - https://jsfiddle.net/s30wo6zy/

Comment: @AnUser you really shouldn't do it with jQuery in 2020. Better way would be to use promises, specifically https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: Here's how to put google API response into a promise https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45796155/how-do-i-promisify-a-callback-from-the-goole-maps-places-api-getplacepredictions

Comment: I tried the method you suggested but I am not able to read the "type" inside the function that is called after getplacepredictions. Can you please help