# Javascript and Jquery problems with return value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-api, return, geocode

this is my code :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        var  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var lat= true;
        var lng = true;

        function codeAddress(address) {
            geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
                if (status == "ZERO_RESULTS"){
                    var lat = 0;
                    var lng = 0;
                }else if (status == "OK"){
                    var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                    var lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                }

            });
          return  lat + "+" + lng;   /// here  i want to return lat & lng
        }

        var nr = $("#get_array").text();
        var my_array = $("#get_array").attr("class");
        my_array = my_array.split("|");
        var string = "";
        for(var i = 0; i < nr; i++){
            item = codeAddress(my_array[i]);
            //string = string + item + "|";
        }
    });
```

where i wrote the comment , there I want to return the lat & lng value , but it is empty. why ??? how can i return the lat and lnb variables ? thx

Comment: i think your both conditions are getting false.

Comment: `geocode` is _asynchronous_. You can't return values from it like you're trying to do.

Comment: is there any other possbile ways ?

Comment: You can get `codeAddress` to add the results to an array and return a deferred object (push each one into an array), and then use [`$.when.apply`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) to access the results array when all the geocodes have completed.

Comment: @Andy can you post an example please ?

Comment: [Here's something I made earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21141001/1377002) - should help you understand, but read the documentation on promises and deferred objects on the jQuery website too.

Comment: this is the first time when I hear about deffered object :)